# Is it possible set the "Use row x as headers" option for a chart using Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm currently trying to build charts with and set the legend labels correctly, but I can't seem to find a way to do this using the API.

Seems like it is possible with Apps Script, but I don't want to do this workaround unless there is no other way.

Here's a picture of what I want
[image]

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike Not sure how this would help, but here: https://pastebin.com/FJhV3te2.
All I can add is that the series range starts on the "Col 1" row

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I couldn't notice `I'm asking if it's possible`. In this case, the answer is yes. But unfortunately, I cannot know your actual chart. So, in the current stage, I cannot propose the sample request body. If you need a sample request body, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the chart? By this, I would like to check it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill, again.

Comment: @Tanaike Link to my request body https://pastebin.com/4vQzaX49 and spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQvTiu3rINoYIpWibuFUeHCUZT6isioCel01ue-KquI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the chart of your sample Spreadsheet is different from your showing image. So, I cannot understand your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to set the "Use row x as headers" option using the API, I can't share the real sheet, but this is the almost the exact result and request I did to make something like that, the data source ranges are the same.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your chart in your sample Spreadsheet, when "Use row x as headers" is used, I think that "condition" is removed. This is your expected situation?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, the legend labels should also include the header titles from the first row, I update the spreadsheet so you can see the expected result.
Headers "Col 1" and "Col 2" are shown in the legend.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, please modify the value of `headerCount` from `0` to `1`. You can find this property in the property of `basicChart`. When UpdateChartSpecRequest is used, the sample request body is as follows.

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateChartSpec": {
        "chartId": ###, <--- Please set your chart ID.
        "spec": {
          "title": "Chart 0",
          "basicChart": {
            "chartType": "COLUMN",
            "axis": [
              {
                "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                "title": "condition",
                "format": {
                  "fontFamily": "Roboto"
                },
                "viewWindowOptions": {}
              },
              {
                "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                "viewWindowOptions": {}
              }
            ],
            "domains": [
              {
                "domain": {
                  "sourceRange": {
                    "sources": [
                      {
                        "startRowIndex": 3,
                        "endRowIndex": 7,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                        "endColumnIndex": 1
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "series": [
              {
                "series": {
                  "sourceRange": {
                    "sources": [
                      {
                        "startRowIndex": 3,
                        "endRowIndex": 7,
                        "startColumnIndex": 1,
                        "endColumnIndex": 2
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS",
                "dataLabel": {
                  "type": "NONE",
                  "textFormat": {
                    "fontFamily": "Roboto"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "series": {
                  "sourceRange": {
                    "sources": [
                      {
                        "startRowIndex": 3,
                        "endRowIndex": 7,
                        "startColumnIndex": 2,
                        "endColumnIndex": 3
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS",
                "dataLabel": {
                  "type": "NONE",
                  "textFormat": {
                    "fontFamily": "Roboto"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "headerCount": 1  <--- This is important modification point.
          },
          "hiddenDimensionStrategy": "SKIP_HIDDEN_ROWS_AND_COLUMNS",
          "titleTextFormat": {
            "fontFamily": "Roboto"
          },
          "fontName": "Roboto"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [UpdateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize `headerCount` was it, I didn't need the update I added it to `addChart` request in `BasicChartSpec` object  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#BasicChartSpec

Comment: @Gny Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.